# Содержание строки python в неправильной кодировке

Tags: python, кодировка

Имеется переменная преобразованная к str.

`a = '\xca\xe0\xf1\xf1\xe0'` (слово на кириллице "Касса").

Необходимо выводить на экран слова на кириллице, в данном случае касса.

Пробовал
`print(a.encode('ascii').decode('utf-8'))`
не получается.

Comment: `a = b'\xca\xe0\xf1\xf1\xe0'
b=b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
print(bytes.decode(a,'cp1251'))
print(bytes.decode(b,'utf8'))` ` Касса
привет`

Comment: на вход поступает такая строка, префикс к ней поставить возможности нет

Comment: смотря откуда поступает, из файла?

Comment: @Daniil_DP откуда поступает? Почему именно в таком виде и что мешает это исправить?

Comment: Я думаю мой ответ Вас устроит

Comment: Принимайте ответ :) Галочку

Comment: @Oopss Поступает из зип архива, файл .dat. при чтении .decode(*любая кодировка*) часть строки (где русские буквы) отображаются как '\xca\xe0\xf1\xf1\xe0' . все остальное, цифры плюс английский, отображается верно.

Comment: При чтении зип файла `open(file, 'w+', encoding='любая кодировка', newline='')` результатов не дает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант такой:

```
import sys

a = '\xca\xe0\xf1\xf1\xe0'
res = bytes(a, 'Latin1').decode('cp1251')
print(f'{sys.stdout.encoding}: {res}')
```

Вывод: utf-8: Касса

Answer (score 0):

1.Байты нужно держать в байт строке, а не в обычной строке

2.Декодировать методом decode

Код ниже должен работать

```
a = "Касса".encode("windows-1251")
a.decode("windows-1251")
```

Comment: Добавлю, что байт строку можно объявить через префикс b: `b'\xca\xe0\xf1\xf1\xe0'`

Comment: Не я храню байт строку в обычной я ее получаю на вход в программу, поэтому и задал такой вопрос.